# How to extract the href within the text using lxml xpath and requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, href, lxml

First of all, I am relatively new to python. I need to extract a link from the text in a web page, I am using lxml with Python 3.5, but i can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
url = someUrl
page = requests.get(url)
webpage = html.fromstring(page.content)
fulllinks = webpage.xpath('//a/@href')
fulltext = webpage.xpath('//a/text()')


for line in fulltext:
    if line.startswith("SomethingHere"):
    'get the link from SomethingHere and do other stuff'
```

where `"somethingHere"` is the text and I want the link from that text (e.g. `www.someweb.com.br/trends`).

I'm kind of lost here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got what i was looking for. The answer is:

```
webpage.xpath("//a[starts-with(text(),'SomethingHere')]/@href")
```

Thanks anyway.